# Can't find tools inside SDK

Tags: android, adt

I use windows-7 32bit . But why I download ADT for 32bit & try to open it , it show me this type of dialogue . I can't understand the problem 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to SDK manager, then open it, then there are some tools in API versions and extras... Download the packages then restart Eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

Go to SDk Manager and from browse locate your SDK folder and click select. then it will load the SDK and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

yes,you can run sdk manager get the sdk folder address then
open eclipse >> window >> Prefrences >> Android 
and copy that address in SDK Location text field